# Homebrew NLopt Python

Tags: python, homebrew, nlopt

I'm trying to install the NLopt library (http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt) from the Homebrew science repository. It installs fine, except that I cannot import NLopt from python. Why is python not able to see the NLopt installation from Homebrew Science?

Answer (score 1):

Which exactly is the error message? Maybe it's the same as I:

I try in python (on windows)

```
import nlopt
```

then the error message is this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/rrenier/Documents/Workspace/GIT/DimORC/Python/test.py",line 3, in <module>
import nlopt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nlopt.py", line 35, in <module>
_nlopt = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nlopt.py", line 31, in swig_import_helper
_mod = imp.load_module('_nlopt', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: DLL load failed: Le module sp�cifi� est introuvable.
```

It seems python tries to find "nlopt.pyd" in the folder "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages" which does not exist (even the installation of nlopt run well).